# Clear values of a CheckBoxList?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have one listBox with check box, when an event end, I need uncheck each check box.

This is my xaml, but in code how can I clear this values? Thanks

```
<ListBox Name="_employeeListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding employeeList}" Margin="409,27,41,301">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding OperatorNum}" Tag="{Binding TheValue}" Checked="CheckBoxZone_Checked"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

  private void _searchProjectsbyEmployeebutton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<EmployeebyProject> employeebyProjectList = new List<EmployeebyProject>();
        if (EmployeeCollectionToInsert.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var employee in EmployeeCollectionToInsert)
            {
                foreach(var employeebyProject in employee.EmployeebyProject)
                {
                    employeebyProjectList.Add(employeebyProject);
                }
            }
            LoadEmployeebyProject(employeebyProjectList);  
            //HERE I NEED UNCHECKED the ListBoxChecked.             
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Please select an employee to search his project."); }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that your applicaiton needs more separation between the View and the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding `ItemsSource` in the `ListBox` and the `ListBox` is using `VirtualizingStackPanel` as its ItemsPanel so all `ListBoxItem` containers may or may not be generated at any given time.
So even if you search the Visual Tree etc. to get all the CheckBoxes to uncheck, you can't be sure that you've unchecked them all.

I suggest you bind `IsChecked` to a new property in the same class as you've defined `OperatorNum` (which, by the looks of your question, probably is Employee or similar). This way, all you need to do to uncheck the CheckBoxes is to set `IsChecked` to `False` in your source class.
Also make sure you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

*Example Xaml*

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0"
          Name="CheckBoxZone"
          Content="{Binding OperatorNum}"
          Tag="{Binding TheValue}"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

*Employee*

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool m_isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return m_isChecked; }
        set
        {
            m_isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
    // Etc..

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx) post explains how you can get the items of a `Template` based `ListBox`. You can use similar technique to find the `CheckBox` and once you have have got the `CheckBox`, checking or unchecking is simple

Comment: The problem is I'm working in wpf, and FindVisualChild not work here, maybe you have other reference to make this...

Comment: The link I posted is a WPF example and `FindViusalChild` definitely works. It's a method written in the same post.